# Tracking scroll position and notifying other components about it

Tags: angular, typescript, events, scroll

Is there an easy way to track the browser scroll position and notify more than a single component about it?

Use case: On scroll I want to be able to change classes of various elements on the page based upon where I am. In a previous version of angular it was somewhat possible through a plugin (same for jQuery). Of course, there is the option of writing bare JS to initialize it on application start and emit an event, but that sounds dirty, and event emission is pretty expensive for this type of thing.

What are my options here?

---

UPDATE (after suggestions):

Here is what I tried:

I created a component:

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: '[track-scroll]',
    host: {'(window:scroll)': 'track($event)'},
    template: ''
})

export class TrackScrollComponent {
    track($event) {
        console.debug("Scroll Event", $event);
    }
}
```

added an attribute to the main directive of an app:

```
<priz-app track-scroll>
```

and added the component as one of the providers in the top component:

```
import {TrackScrollComponent} from "../../shared/components/track-scroll.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'priz-app',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, SecureRouterOutlet, AppHeader, TrackScrollComponent],
  providers: [AuthenticationService]
})
```

Still nothing...

---

ANOTHER UPDATE:

Moved `track-scroll` to one of the div elements of the main template:

```
<div class="container-fluid" track-scroll>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <app-header></app-header>
            <secure-outlet signin="Login" unauthorized="AccessDenied"></secure-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now the app loads with a completely empty screen.
FUN FUN FUN...

---

FINAL SOLUTION (that worked for me).

1. Define a directive:

```
import {Directive} from "angular2/core";

@Directive({
    selector: '[track-scroll]',
    host: {'(window:scroll)': 'track($event)'}
})

export class TrackScrollDirective {
    track($event: Event) {
        console.debug("Scroll Event", $event);
    }
}
```

2. Add it as a directive everywhere that uses it:

```
directives: [TrackScrollDirective]
```

3. Add the attribute to each element we want to track the event:

```
<div class="col-md-12" track-scroll>
```

Comment: Next question is, what is the best way to propagate that to another component?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by propagate? You can just emit using an `@Output()` and bind it to an `@Input()` of another component. I added a comment to my answer about `directives: [...]`.

Comment: Basically, I want to use this information in other component. Do I have to do it through `EventEmitter`?

Comment: Yes, you can use `@Output() scrollPos:EventEmitter` and `@Input() scrollPos` on the receiving component and bind in the template if they are parent-child.

Comment: Opened separate question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471927/eventemitter-does-not-work-on-chrome-safari

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I think the easiest way is each interested component listening to the scroll event.

```ts
  @Component({
    ...
    // alternative to `@HostListener(...)`
    // host: {'(window:scroll)': 'doSomething($event)'}
  })
  class SomeComponent {
    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) 
    doSomething(event) {
      // console.debug("Scroll Event", document.body.scrollTop);
      // see András Szepesházi's comment below
      console.debug("Scroll Event", window.pageYOffset );
    }
  }
```

**[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3m8hjU?p=preview)**

**[Plunker using `@HostListener()`](https://plnkr.co/edit/AT7D6O?p=preview)**

Hint:

```ts
bootstrap(MyComponent, [
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [TrackScrollDirective], multi:true})]);
```

makes the directive universal without adding it to every components `directive: [...]` list.

Comment: By the way, the option with `HostListener` does not work for some reason. Didn;t spend time digging into it.

Comment: I added another Plunker link utilizing `@HostListener()`

Comment: Well, I did exactly that, the only difference is that in my case it is a directive, not a component.

Comment: Error in :0:0 caused by: self.context.doSomething is not a function

Comment: When doing what? I can't reproduce with any of the two Plunker above.

Comment: For browser cross-compatibility, use window.pageYOffset instead of document.body.scrollTop, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer How to implement this as a service?

Comment: You would just need to use `window.addEventListener('scroll', this.doSomething.bind(this))` instead of `@HostListener(...)`

Comment: The angular2 documentation has an example of using @HostListener with a directive where the first argument of the decorator is an event tied to the host element i.e. the element that the directive is acting on. In your example, you have 'window:scroll' working from within a component instead of a host element. How did you figure it'd be 'window:scroll' (with the colon) instead of 'window.scroll' (with a period)? Were you able to find any doc on this somewhere?

Comment: `window:scroll` means Angular registers the event handler on the `window` object. I don't think `window.scroll` is valid at all. Perhaps emitting a custom event with the mame `window.scroll` is possible, but that could as well be any other name - `window.` has no special meaning here, while `window:` has. The later is for global event targets. I'm sure it is mentioned somewhere in the docs, but I easn't able to find it.

Comment: Window scroll only works on the top level element body / html. How to listen to an element scroll? Or on the scrollTop property. Or another way to trigger if the element is in the view.

Comment: `(scroll)="eventhandler"` on any element that is scrollable.

Answer (score 14):

I was forced to solve this differently because I needed to watch several scrolling elements on the window. I created a directive to watch the scroll position on an element:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[scroll]'
})
export class ScrollDir {
  @Output() setScroll = new EventEmitter();
  private scroll: number;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
  scrollIt() { this.scroll = event.srcElement.scrollTop }

  reset() {  this.el.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.scroll }
}
```

Then on any any component containing a scroll element that needed this element I could `@ViewChild` the directive like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <div class="container" scroll>
      // *ngFor=""...
    </div>
  `
})
export class ParentComp implements AfterViewChecked {

  @ViewChild(ScrollDir) scroll: ScrollDir;

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.scroll.reset()
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for those who are looking for scroll event inside a DOM element that is not the window. In my case, I am tracking the scroll of a <div> nested down the DOM tree. `event.srcElement.scrollTop` works like a charm

Answer (score 11):

Look at the source to [ScrollService](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/src/app/shared/scroll.service.ts), as part of the angular documentation project.

The way they get the position is `fromEvent(window, 'scroll')`

You can then do something like this in a global service you inject into your component:

```
public readonly windowScroll$ = fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(map(x => window.scrollY), startWith(0), distinctUntilChanged(), shareReplay(1));
```

The `startWith(0)` is needed because you may not get a scroll event until you actually scroll. You can add debouncing if needed.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, i needed to scroll a div when user scroll a page, and solved my problem with the code below.
At the component where you want to capture the scroll:

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('curtain') divCurtain: ElementRef;

export class ComponentX {
    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScrollEvent($event) {
        console.log(window.pageYOffset);
        this.divCurtain.nativeElement.style.top = window.pageYOffset.toString().concat('px');
    }

    ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

Only this, i did not create any directive or other code.
This `HostListener` is executed every time the user scroll the page, and i get the `window.pageYOffset` to send to my div.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In angular we can track the scroll position inside a div using viewchild events.

First add a reference in html

```
<div #postion class="scroll-container">
  .......
  .......
</div>
```

Declare the ref in ts file using viewchild

```
@ViewChild('postion', { static: true }) _div: ElementRef;
```

Then inside ngAfterViewInit function

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
     fromEvent(this._div?.nativeElement, 'scroll').subscribe((e: any) =>  {
         this.scrollPosition = e?.target['scrollTop'];
            });
  }
```

Import fromEvent from rxjs.

And If you want to scroll to this saved position later, then you can do

```
      (this._div.nativeElement as HTMLElement).scrollTop = this.scrollPosition;
```