# Show Navigation bar after Scroll down in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Hey I want to show a Navigationbar after my user scroll down about 200px.

For now I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468318/tracking-scroll-position-and-notifying-other-components-about-it-angular2) solution. And it works like a charm. But I doesn't fount anything how to get the scroll position.

Maybe you can help me here. Maybe the event has the position but I don't found it in the developer console.

Thanks in advance
Dominic

Answer (score 0):

After searching further I found this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471927/eventemitter-does-not-work-on-chrome-safari).

I now have a Method looking like:

```
 @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  showNavbar(event): void {
    console.log("Scrolling" + document.body.scrollTop);
  }
```

This one seemes to work verry well.