# How can I scroll programmatically a div in Angular 2 pages?

Tags: angularjs, angular, scroll, angular2-template

I have link top like:

```
<a href="#scroll">Test</a>
```

Onclick this i want to scroll page to div which contains id scroll

```
<div id="#scroll">Testing scrolling in Angualar 2</div>
```

Comment: try `[href]='#scroll'`

Comment: @AtalKishore Its not working getting Parser Error: Unexpected token # in [#scroll]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tracking scroll position and notifying other components about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468318/tracking-scroll-position-and-notifying-other-components-about-it)