# Angular Equivalent of jQuery MouseWheel

Tags: jquery, angular

Does anyone know what the angular equivalent of `mousewheel` is?

I basically need to be able to do the following in Angular but can't find much information about it

`$(document).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {...`

The website I am working on has `overflow: hidden` on it, which means there is no scrollbar and window scrolling won't work. I just need to be able to detect a scroll event to fire a function. Onscroll only works when the scrollbar actually moves

Thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tracking scroll position and notifying other components about it (Angular2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468318/tracking-scroll-position-and-notifying-other-components-about-it-angular2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[wheel]'
})
class WheelDirective {

 @HostListener('wheel', ['$event']) 
  Wheel(event) {
   console.log('wheel');
  }
}

<div wheel class="wheel">..long text</div>

.wheel {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: What a ridiculous syntax. Google needs to stop the madness.